# div or p tag inside of flex box wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to have the logo text div tag called Title take up its content space inside the parent flexbox instead of wrapping.

I don't want to set the Title which is just a div to 100% or use white-space:nowrap. I just want it to act like a div where it fills its content space and only wraps if it needs too.

Also why does this happen when another element is set to 100%. Like the code snippet below.

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const Header = styled.div `
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  background-color: #147189;
  color: white;
`;

const Title = styled.div `
`;
const TestDiv = styled.div `
   width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

const App = () => {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <Header >
        <Title > Logo Text </Title> 
        <TestDiv > hello </TestDiv> </Header> 
      </div>
     );
  }

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: `Title` is breaking up at a space to take as little space as possible, since it has no width property and `TestDiv` has `100%`. So it is currently behaving as "where it fills its content space and only wraps if it needs to".

Comment: Thanks cSharp, so how can I get around this wrapping without knowing the exact space the text will fill up. What happens if the text is dynamic where you would not know the exact width of the text ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%` from the `TestDiv` definition and add `margin-left: 2rem` (or whatever value you wish) to separate it from the other flex item (i.e the `Title` component):

```
const TestDiv = styled.div `
    margin-left: 2rem; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
`;
```

Alternatively, you could set the widths for the flex items as percentages (totaling 100%) of their parent's (`Header's)` width, like below:

```
const Title = styled.div `
    width: 10%;
`;

const TestDiv = styled.div `
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid red;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not want to use `whitespace: nowrap`, I guess a workaround would be to parameterise the width of the `Title` div according to the title text. I set `width` of `Title` to be equal to `width + 3 ch` (3 extra just for padding and make sure it does not wrap). I guess if this might get too long, you could set `max-width: 25ch` or something like that.

Hope this helps.

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const Header = styled.div `
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  background-color: #147189;
  color: white;
`;

const Title = styled.div `
`;
const TestDiv = styled.div `
   width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;


const style = () => ({});

const setWidth = (width) => ({
  width: `${width + 3}ch`,
});

const App = () => {

    
    return ( 
      <div>
        <Header >
        <Title style={ setWidth('Logo Text Whatever'.length) } > Logo Text Whatever </Title> 
        <TestDiv > hello </TestDiv> </Header> 
      </div>
     );
  }

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```